# Avoid repetition in Definition of Regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am writing a regex to match the contents of a textbox, that should contain numbers and number ranges and commas separating these elements e.g:

```
123, 123-422, 2323, 22-333
```

etc.

The regex for it is:

```
^(((\s*[0-9]+\s*)|((\s*[0-9]+\s*)-(\s*[0-9]+\s*)))(,((\s*[0-9]+\s*)|((\s*[0-9]+\s*)-(\s*[0-9]+\s*))))*)$
```

which is not pretty, in fact quite repetitious, but I defined it with C# code:

```
var num = @"(\s*[0-9]+\s*)";
var range = string.Format("({0}-{0})", num);
var numOrRange = string.Format("({0}|{1})", num, range);
var regex = string.Format("^({0}(,{0})*)$", numOrRange);
```

is there any feature within regular expression syntax which enables you to define "groups" (and assign a name to it) and then reuse those "groups"?  The above regex code is fairly mainainable but I would prefer not using `string.format` for defining reg expressions.

Comment: Yes. .NET has the feature: named capturing group.

Comment: You can define a named capturing group, however you can't use it as a reference to a subpattern later (you can only refer to the matched content)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: You CAN backreference with named capturing group, use `\k<name>`.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Casimir is right. \k<name> doesn't refer to the subexpression, but the actual value that was captured by the named group.

Comment: Oh, so that was what he meant (subroutine vs. backreference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the problem is repitition in this case.
I think the problem is that it can't be seen in a meaningfull way.
For the life of me, I can't wrap my head around that programmers still
insist on compressing expressions when they should format them like code.

Most all engines have the expanded modifier either as an inline construct or an external option. Regex's should *always* be formatted within the source code.

Your regex uses a very fast unrolled method and it should stay that way.
Even if Dot-Net provided recursive calls, and they don't, it is not the way
to go with your regex.  Stick with what you've got.

After some paring down of parenthes, it should not be a problem either seeing what it does or in performance.

```
 // @"^\s*[0-9]+(?:\s*-\s*[0-9]+)?(?:\s*,\s*[0-9]+(?:\s*-\s*[0-9]+)?)*"     
 Regex rx = new Regex(
   @"
      ^ 
      \s*     
      [0-9]+ 
      (?: \s* - \s* [0-9]+ )?
      (?:
           \s* , \s* 
           [0-9]+ 
           (?: \s* - \s* [0-9]+ )?
      )*
   ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: @Tahir Hassan - Not in Dot-Net. They have balanced groups (a stack) but its not the same as a subroutine (typically called recurse a group _subexpression_). If it were PCRE/Perl flavor, you could use the `(?&name)` construct to make the call. For your regex, that would probably look like this -> `^(?<Num>\s*[0-9]+(?:\s*-\s*[0-9]+)?)(?:\s*,(?&Num))*`  Good Luck!

Comment: Just a note. Its typically a recursion when called within the named group, and a sub call when called external. Many engine rules apply to carry out this feat, including context stack interaction, that requires ways to control backtracking such as atomic groups and possesive quantifiers. In a simple case this is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something like this:

```
var regex = @"^(?:[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?(?:, |$))+$";
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand what you need, this will do the job:

```
^(((\s*[0-9]+\s*)|((?3)-(?3)))(,(?2))*)$
```

The notation `(?NUM)` says that the part NUM is re-used ie. `\s*[0-9]+\s*`.

`(?3)` is `\s*[0-9]+\s*`
`(?2)` is `(((\s*[0-9]+\s*)|((?3)-(?3)))`

Comment: I think this recursive construct `(?2)` is specific to Perl/PCRE, not Dot-Net.